# The cmd closes without finishing the process in C++

Tags: c++

When I run the code below, it takes my input and then the cmd closes without giving any error, the same Logic is used to Java and it worked.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string s;
int l = s.length();
int i,flag = 0;
cin >> s;
char c;

for(i = 0; i < l; i++){

    while(i<l && s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0'){
            char c = s[i];
            cout << c;
            i++;
            flag++;
    }
    if( flag > 0){
        flag = 0;
        cout << " ";
    }

}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Console would close when code goes to `return 0`.

Comment: Btw, do not use l as a variable name, as it may be confused with a 1, depending on the fonts. In general, use descriptive variable names, you get no benefit in "saving" code characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just like nacho searles said, your console is closed because work is done. A `cin.get()` or other blocking code could keep console not closing.
2. Since C++ is pass by value by default, your assignment of `l` doesn't link to `s.length()` dynamically. Your for loop would run 0 times.

You may assign value to s before getting its length.

```
string s;
cin >> s;
int l = s.length();
```

3. It seems `i` isn't needed out of for loop, you may define `i` in for loop like
   `for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering my question.. I fixed all of this mistakes from 2 and 3.. I also added the code in 1. However, what happens when I run, the cmd gives me chance to type my string input then the cmd types `Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.868 s`

Comment: @OmarShokeir I don't get your question. If you have an ide, you may put breakpoints to see the status of variables. `Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.868 s ` seems like the ouptut of debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this before you return 0:

```
cin.get();
```

The console is getting closed before you are able to read the output.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SO!

It is okay that your program is closing after execution. It is closed because it riched the

```
return 0;
```

line. It automatically closes on this line.

Everything you should do to slow down the closing is to wait before

```
return 0;
```

You can wait user's input adding line this way:

```
cin >> s;
return 0;
```

It is the most common solution in your case.

Answer (score 0):

So I have made some changes and the code worked.. Although the code ran, it still have errors.

`cin >> s;` was changed to `getline (cin, s);`

`char c = s[i];` and `cout << c;` was changed to `cout << s[i];`

Comment: This is not an answer, especially since you say you still have errors but don’t say what they are. Instead you should probably either add a comment, or ask a completely new question (listing your new code).